# How to add button or link to YII2 Gridview::FILTER_DATE

Tags: php, yii2

I am trying to add button or link to the filter_date popup calendar to allow filtering gridview not only by particular date but also to display null values only (like excel autofilter empty values).
[image: gridview example]

On Search model i setup query :
`($this->delivery_date)=="null" ? $query->andWhere(['delivery_date' => null,]) : $query->andFilterWhere(['delivery_date' => $this->delivery_date]);`

Now i need to allow in search field 'null' value apart of date.
Is there a simple way to modify calendar widget ?

Comment: Can you show me your GridView look like?

Comment: This is the column of gridview i'd like to modify it uses kartik date picker component

`'attribute' =>  'wh_entry_date',
      'filterType' => GridView::FILTER_DATE,
      'filterWidgetOptions' => [
        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Enter birth date ...'],
        'pluginOptions' => [
          'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd',
          'todayHighlight' => true,
          'autoclose' => true,
          'todayHighlight' => true,
          'weekStart' =>'1',
          'showButtonPanel'=>'true',
          'showTodayButton' => 'true'
          ]
        ],`